# Finding the names of columns with a common value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'fiction' created in MySQL. The table looks like this

**fiction:**

| id | name | gender | image | browser | os |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chris | male | 1 | 0 | ios |
| 2 | emma | female | 1 | 1 | ios |
| 3 | james | male | 0 | 0 | android |
| 4 | lucas | male | 1 | 0 | android |
| 5 | amelia | female | 0 | 1 | ios |
| 6 | olivia | female | 1 | 0 | ios |

What I want to do is to retrieve the names of the columns where the records in the 'gender' column have the value 'male', and all other columns have the same value. For example, If I run this code:

`SELECT * FROM fiction WHERE gender = "male";`

The output will be:

| id | name | gender | image | browser | os |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chris | male | 1 | 0 | ios |
| 3 | james | male | 0 | 0 | android |
| 4 | lucas | male | 1 | 0 | android |

As you can see, the 'browser' column has a common value of '0' in all records. So I want this column name, 'browser'. Another example:

`SELECT * FROM fiction WHERE gender = "female";`

Output:

| id | name | gender | image | browser | os |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | emma | female | 1 | 1 | ios |
| 5 | amelia | female | 0 | 1 | ios |
| 6 | olivia | female | 1 | 0 | ios |

As you can see here, the 'os' column has a common value in all of them. I need an SQL statement that will show me these common columns.

I used GROUP BY and HAVING expressions, but as you can guess, they didn't solve my problem. I think I need to do something related to the information_schema table.

Comment: Could you put question into https://www.db-fiddle.com/  to make it easy for us to test a possible solution?  And share your fiddle link, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT 'name' col, name, count(*) c FROM mytable WHERE gender = 'male' group by name union all
   SELECT 'gender', gender, count(*) c FROM mytable WHERE gender = 'male' group by gender union all
   SELECT 'image', image, count(*) c FROM mytable WHERE gender = 'male' group by image union all
   SELECT 'browser', browser, count(*) c FROM mytable WHERE gender = 'male' group by browser union all
   SELECT 'os', os, count(*) c FROM mytable WHERE gender = 'male' group by os 
   
) x
WHERE x.c = (SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE gender = 'male');
;
```

Solution for `female` is the same, just replace 'male' by 'female'.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/dUIg27qB)

Comment: OMG. Wow. You actually understood me very well. This is what I was looking for. And solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A small problem with the question is that 'male' and 'female' have the same count. This should be avoided when asking question like this, to make the problem easier to read (in general).   But, as a bonus, i added a final SQL: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/RLAv-tAG)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't explain what exact outcome you want, i show you for an example how to do it and then you can extend it to your purposes

Then basic idea is that the group  can have only the count of distinct values of 1, if you are searching for common values

The query bleow finds also all common columns

```
WITH cnt as (
  SELECT 
  COUNT( DISTINCT `image`) img,
  COUNT(DISTINCT `os`) osc
  , COUNT(DISTINCT `browser`)  brws
  FROM fiction WHERE gender = "male"
  )
SELECT
 `id`, `name`, `gender`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
  CASE WHEN brws = 1 THEN 'browser' ELSE '' END ,
  CASE WHEN osc = 1 THEN 'ios'  ELSE '' END ,
  CASE WHEN img = 1 THEN 'image'  ELSE ''  END ) gc

FROM fiction CROSS JOIN cnt
WHERE gender = "male"
  GROUP BY `id`, `name`, `gender`
```

| id | name | gender | gc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chris | male | browser |
| 3 | james | male | browser |
| 4 | lucas | male | browser |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qQuVmxSb)

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea:

Count distinct values, and if it is equal to 1, then return desired name (column name for your case), and if it is not return "-". Finally add the output strings together.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  IF((count(distinct(os))=1), "os", '-'),
  ',',
  IF((count(distinct(browser))=1), "browser", '-'),
  ',',
  IF((count(distinct(image))=1), "image", '-')
) FROM FICTION WHERE gender = "female";
```

The output is: `os,-,-`

If you are sure that you have only one common column, you can replace "-" with an empty string and remove the ',' from CONCAT. So query will be like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   IF((count(distinct(os))=1), "os", ''),
   IF((count(distinct(browser))=1), "browser", ''),
   IF((count(distinct(image))=1), "image", '')
) FROM FICTION WHERE gender = "female";
```

And the ouput is: `os`.

Comment: Yup, just like answer of @Luuk your answer is also solved my problem. Thanks a lot!